# Create a cmd shortcut which opens URL with lot of query string

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Well I have created cmd shortcut to open multiple URL in chrome

`START https://mywebsite.com/something/morething/abc.html`

Above one works fine, but this does not when url is longer and having `multiple query string`.

`START https://mywebsite.com/something/morething/abc.html?checkin=2018-07-21&los=1&adults=2&rooms=1&cid=-1&searchrequestid=68159c43-71a5-4dc9-9cb1-35a82ed8e8d8&tabbed=true`

So when I click bat file it just accept first query string and ignores other.

So URL opened by chrome is 
`https://mywebsite.com/something/morething/abc.html?checkin=2018-07-21` instead of opening full url with query string.

Any way to fix this and open whole URL via cmd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not only add `""` in your link?

```
start "" "https://mywebsite.com/something/morething/abc.html?checkin=2018-07-21&los=1&adults=2&rooms=1&cid=-1&searchrequestid=68159c43-71a5-4dc9-9cb1-35a82ed8e8d8&tabbed=true"
```

Comment: I confirm, it works fine

Comment: @ankitd thank you for test

Comment: Accepted this answer as its much easier to do this way then above one by Alex. Although both works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special CMD's character `&` by prefixing it with character `^`

This should work

```
@echo off

set "_link=https://mywebsite.com/something/morething/abc.html?checkin=2018-07-21^&los=1^&adults=2^&rooms=1^&cid=-1^&searchrequestid=68159c43-71a5-4dc9-9cb1-35a82ed8e8d8&tabbed=true"

START %_link%
```